# How to access Aache SOLR custom request handler /suggest from solrj or spring data for solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, spring-data

I'm new to Solr. I'm implementing auto complete functionality for my application.  I have configured the required fields in solr and created a custom request handler /suggest. I'm finding it tricky to access it via solr java client solrj. I'm even fine with the spring data for solr. Please somebody help to access my custom request handler from solr java client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With spring-data-solr you might add `@Query(requestHandler = "/suggest")` or use `query.setRequestHandler("/suggest")`.
In case you're doing autocomplete you might also give `/terms` and the `SimpleTermsQuery` a try.

Comment: How can we retrieve the suggestions? I mean, what is the response type in this case?

Answer (score 2):

SolrJ supports this through the use of the `setRequestHandler` method on the `SolrQuery` class.